# Risk and Risk-Management Tags. Is there a difference, or should we merge them?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed that we have a [risk](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/risk) tag and a [risk-management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/risk-management) tag. I'm not sure I really see a difference. There's also a [schedule-risk](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schedule-risk) tag.

Is there a good reason to not merge these together? Or would it be easier to find questions about risks if these questions all shared a common tag?

Comment: Maybe "risk" is more about individual risks? As long as it isn't a meta-tag, it just might need some redefinition on where to apply it.

Comment: Hi @CodeGnome, I looked at the questions in both tags, and they all seem geared towards risks in a project, not really risks that affect individual people. There are 23 questions tagged "risk" and 29 tagged "risk-management". 12 of the questions share *both* tags. If you don't mind taking a look as well, that would be awesome, as I'm thinking of retagging them all as risk-management if no one sees any strong reason not to.

Comment: If you merge them, I'd recommend merging to `risk-management` because that's more specific, less meta, and more likely to draw attention to controls than instead of "what can go wrong?" lists.

Comment: @CodeGnome - Awesome! This reminds me to go ahead and knock this out. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'd put risk and risk management in the same bucket of being general categories of which schedule risk is a sub-set.  There's not a huge volume of any particular one.

I'd vote for merging them all into risk management.  Strikes me as more project management oriented and thus more likely to be a match for a search on the topic (from Google or within PMSE).

Comment: This is what I'm thinking too. After [looking at the questions](http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/questions/565/risk-and-risk-management-tags-is-there-a-difference-or-should-we-merge-them#comment931_565), it seems almost half of them share both tags.